# Questions Needing Edits

Tags: discussion, editing, off-topic

There are a couple questions needing edits to line them up with the scope defined within the FAQ. The questions here are some good questions that have been flagged as off-topic, and it would be nice if we could make them tie-in more directly with fitness/exercise.

[Is there a biological reason for women to be weaker then men (in the same weight category)?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3163/is-there-a-biological-reason-for-women-to-be-weaker-then-men-in-the-same-weight)

I'll try to do my best to maintain this list with items as they get updated or come into focus.

**Done:**

[What are BCAAs, and what are they used for?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2456/what-are-bcaa-and-what-are-they-used-for)
 -- Thanks, @Greg!

Comment: Hi Nathan, one suggestion, make this community wiki or encourage others to locate questions that could be edited. Some of us have an eye for *finding* questions that need TLC, but we may not be the same people who can actually *give* the questions the TLC as we may not be in that same creative, editing mindset. :) Hope this helps!

Comment: @jmort253 - done!